# Deadbeef : finding all words made of hexadecimal digits

Tags: c, file

Hexadecimal `0xdead, 0xbeef` are the magic numbers because they're also English words. 
I decided to find such words as many as possible. How to do it? We need large English text let's say [Ulysses by James Joyce](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/4300) and a program which extracts all words consists of hexadecimal digits. For simplicity, I decided to drop leet-language support. It dramatically shrinks the range but keeps real words only.

The code below extract magic numbers from given text and prints them to stdout in lower case

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 256

int process_file(FILE* file);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  if (argc == 1) {
    process_file(stdin);
  } else {
    size_t i = 0;
    char* filename;
    FILE* file;
    int err;
    while ((filename = argv[++i]) != NULL) {
      file = fopen(filename, "r");
      if (!file) {
        perror("fopen() failed");
        return 1;
      }
      err = process_file(file);
      fclose(file);
      if (err) {
        return 2;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

int process_file(FILE* file) {
  char word[MAX_LEN];
  size_t p = 0;
  int c;
  while (1) {
    c = getc(file);
    if (isspace(c) || c == EOF) {
      /* end of word or end of emptiness */

      if (p > 0 && p < MAX_LEN && p % 2 == 0) {
        word[p] = 0;
        printf("%s\n", word);
      }

      if (c == EOF) {
        break;
      }

      p = 0;
      continue;
    }

    if (p > MAX_LEN - 1) {
      continue;
    }

    if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')) { /* abcdef ABCDEF */
      word[p++] = tolower(c);
    } else {
      /* skip this word */
      p = MAX_LEN;
    }
  }

  if (feof(file)) {
    return 0;
  }

  if (ferror(file)) {
    perror("i/o error occurred");
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Commands

```
echo "Dead of being fed with beef for a decade" | ./deadbeaf | sort | uniq
```

should give

```
beef
dead
decade
```

Comment: "magic numbers because they're also English words" --> Why does output not include `"fed"`.  I see that is because code has `&& p % 2 == 0`, yet my questions is why choose the functionality to drop odd length words?

Comment: @chux good point. I assumed have output similar to machine word. Probably it better to reconsider

Comment: Concerning  `MAX_LEN`, [Longest word in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_English) is interesting.

Comment: @chux have you seen longer ?

Comment: It is not that I have seen longer or not, it is that it is useful to justify magic numbers like 256 with some reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is customary to put helper functions first and `main()` last, to avoid having to write forward declarations like `int process_file(FILE* file);`.

`process_file()` is a very generic name.  I suggest renaming it to `print_hex_words()`.

The `process_file()` function returns an error code.  Therefore, the responsibility for printing any error message for I/O errors should lie with `main()`.

You assume that words are delimited by whitespace, and have neglected to deal with punctuation.

Your algorithm is very tedious.  Instead of using `getc()` to read a byte at a time, [use `fscanf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16401033/1157100) to read a whitespace-delimited word at a time.  To skip to the end of a sequence consisting solely of A-F characters, use [`strspn(…, "ABCDEFabcdef")`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strspn.html).

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s

int print_hex_words(FILE* file) {
    char word_buf[MAX_LEN + 1];
    while (1 == fscanf(file, "%" xstr(MAX_LEN) "s", word_buf)) {
        char *word, *end, *trail_punct;

        /* Skip leading punctuation */
        for (word = word_buf; ispunct(*word); word++);

        end = word + strspn(word, "ABCDEFabcdef");

        /* Skip trailing punctuation */
        for (trail_punct = end; ispunct(*trail_punct); trail_punct++);

        if (word != end && *trail_punct == '\0') {
            /* NUL-terminate the word and convert it to lowercase */
            *end = '\0';
            for (end = word; (*end = tolower(*end)); end++);

            printf("%s\n", word);
        }
    }
    return ferror(file);
}
```

Instead of `… | sort | uniq`, you can use `… | sort -u`.

Comment: Leading `" " ` in `" %"` unnecessary - yet OK.  `-1 != fscanf(...` **assumes** `EOF == -1`.  Better to use `1 == fscanf(...` here anyways.

Comment: Could you add an explanation of the `xstr` and `str` macros? I don't quite get what they are doing (I understand that it has to do with creating a format string like `"%25s"` at compile time, but why two macros?).

Comment: @mkrieger1 The `xstr()` macro comes out of the [GNU CPP documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing).